# how to clear json object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var json=[];
json.push({"id":"1","name":"abc"});
json.push({"id":"2","name":"xyz"});
```

after push my json like this

```
json=[{"id":"1","name":"abc"},{"id":"2","name":"xyz"}];
```

Here i want to clear all the `json` data

like this `json=[]`

Is it possible in `jquery` or `javascript` ?

Comment: You can do it exactly like you suggested. That will simply overwrite the contents of `json` with a new, empty array.

Comment: Erm... and what's wrong with `json = []`? Actually, I'm not sure why do you need this at all: if `json` variable is properly localized, it will be released after it goes out of scope.

Comment: I prefer `json = new Array();` to `[]` :)

Comment: Would have been pretty trivial to simply try it out, but yes `json = []` would work.

Comment: @Jimbo: Why that?! It's vastly less readable, IMO

Comment: @NiklasB. So `new Array` is *vastly* less readable than `[]`? Okay then...

Comment: @Jimbo: No, the other way round.

Comment: @NiklasB. I guess it's down to preference / opinion then :) That's why I said "I prefer..." as opposed to "This is better..."

Comment: json.length=0 is working for me thanks all

Comment: @Jimbo Also why? `Array` can be redefined, while `[]` can't. Array ctors with args isn't always intuitive (one arg vs. n). It's also longer with no additional communication or value, and matches other languages' array syntax. I thought the nail on `new Array()` was last nailed several years ago.

Comment: @DaveNewton Fair point, after doing some research it seems `[]` is actually **faster** than `new Array()` - which is the principal reason I'll make the switch. I still preferred stating Array though as opposed to [], and as I said - that was just personal opinion.

Answer (score 6):

reset to empty array

```
json= [];
```

I think this solve your problem

Comment: ya this is the answer i want thank u

Comment: Your answer deletes the reference of existing json array and creates a new reference to that array. So json.length = 0 would be a better answer for this

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is:

```
json.length = 0;
```

this will also free any memory associated with the object.

You could also delete the object with the `delete` command:

```
delete json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the following:

```
json.splice(0,json.length);
```

Comment: Isn't `json.length = 0` enough in this case? )